# CREATE MYSQL DATABASE error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a db using this script

```
    //CREATE MYSQL DATABASE
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $config['database'] . " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {
    $query = "USE " . $config['database'];
    if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {
        $progress .= "Database " . $config['database'] . " set up successfully.<br>";
    }
} else {
    return_error("MySQL connection successful but error setting up database: " . $connection->error);
}
```

and i got this error without being able to identify the problem. Any ideas ?

MySQL connection successful but error setting up database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1

Thanks

Comment: You might need a semicolon at the end of your `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

Comment: tried like this but it doesn't make any difference. still the same issue $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $config['database'] . " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";

Comment: Echo the full query you're executing. You may be using a database name that needs backticks.

Comment: (Please put the error message in a block quote (precede with `> `).)

Comment: Yes, print `$config['database']`, the problem could be only with the database name.